# Reporting Services Install/Uninstall Fails "Input String..."

Tags: sql-server-2008, windows-7, reporting-services

I have done my best to install a copy of SQL Server 2008, but have discovered my "Reporting Services" installation has failed.

Furthermore, when I attempt to "repair" both the installation (and the "Shared Components" only, per a work-around I found here, will update with link if I find it) I have no had any success, as the SQL Server 2008 SP1 Patch reports that there are issues with my server's previous installation.

When I follow the procedure to complete uninstall SQL Server 2008 for a clean install (following instructions such as removing all components via the control panel "Uninstall") I also recieve errors, and when I attempt to re-run the installer I find that the instance I previously attempted to remove still exists: "MSSQL10" for example (see screen shot), and "RS" is listed as it's components, leading me to believe that the uninstall is failing because of this "RS" issue!

I have redownloaded the installer media, and tried to re-running it, and get the same issues when I choose a new name for an instances, and try "adding" features to the one I CANNOT seem uninstall! Any advice would be very helpful, my goal is to uninstall all instances of SQL Server 2008, start fresh, and apply the SP1 patch.

Thanks. I have attached log file, and screen shot. Computer information: Windows 7 Pro. 
HP G60

Some error messages:

TITLE: SQL Server Setup failure.

Input string was not incorrect format.

I have pictures but not enough "reputation" to post them )-8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I experienced this problem as well - someone suggests it is corrupted Perfmon counters:

I found this ( http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlsetupandupgrade/thread/c9cb944d-6264-4530-9e00-ee92da3e939f/ ):

================================
Got this one figured out.  The performance counters were corrupted.   You can see this by opening perfmon and noticing a bunch of numbers instead of the actual counters themselves.
In order to fix (or you might want to check before you install), run:
c:\windows\system32\lodctr /R

## This will reload the performance counters

This worked.

Comment: Thanks Peter, I agree, I found this material as well and attempted this fix, it either failed, or the "write-up" on how to fix it looked way too complicated (more so than just flashing my operating systems) Either way, I had some extra time to do, but I would def. recommend that fix for anyone else experiencing this problem (at least try it!) 

Good luck!